# Как можно максимально сократить этот код?

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

Морской бой. Пишу метод для поворота корабля.

`tt` - это текущее положение корабля:

> 0 - вертикально (по умолчанию)
>
> 1 - горизонтально (0 + 90°)
>
> 2 - вертикально (0 вверх ногами)
>
> 3 - горизонтально (0 - 90°)

`ckw` - это флаг поворота:

> `true` - по часовой стрелке
>
> `false` - против часовой стрелки

Код метода поворота:

```
public void turn (boolean ckw) {
    if ((tt == 0 && !ckw) || (tt == 1 && ckw)) {
        //b -> c
    }
    else if ((tt == 1 && !ckw) || (tt == 2 && ckw)) {
        //c -> d
    }
    else if ((tt == 2 && !ckw) || (tt == 3 && ckw)) {
        //d -> a
    }
    else if ((tt == 3 && !ckw) || (tt == 0 && ckw)) {
        //a -> b
    }
    if (ckw)
        tt++;
    else
        tt--;
}
```

Комментариями обозначены 4 цикла `for-each` с логикой разворота. Мне бы вот эту лесенку `if`-ов сократить. Это возможно?

**Логика поворота**

Корабль представляет собой `ArrayList` позиций в сетке. Например, 4-палубный, находящийся в середине поля: `35, 45, 55, 65`. Чтобы его повернуть по часовой стрелке, надо прибавить к каждой позиции её индекс, умноженный на `11`.

b -> c (90° -> 180°) или (0° -> 270°)

```
for (int i = 0; i < col.size(); i++) {
    int num = col.get(i);
    int new_num = num + 11 * i;
    col.set(i, new_num);
}
```

И т.д.

Comment: кто такие `b -> c`, `c -> d` и прочие звери? и что за `вертикально (0 вверх ногами)` ? Какие еще ноги у кораблей?

Comment: Комментарии? Не обращайте на них внимания, дело не в них. Корабль вверх ногами? А кву ещё это объяснить? Два раза по часовой стрелке повернуть на 45° вот тебе и вверх ногами

Comment: А как выглядит код самого поворота? Вполне возможно, что эти четыре  поворота (`a -> b`  и другие) можно объединить в единый код и необходимость в `if-else` (или `switch-case`) вообще отпадёт.

Comment: Ещё непонятно почему для `tt == 0 && !ckw` и `tt == 1 && ckw` одинаковый код поворота, если в первом случае это поворот от 0 до 270 градусов, а во втором случае - от 90 до 180.

Comment: @Regent `Вполне возможно, что эти четыре поворота (a -> b и другие) можно объединить в единый код` - да, спасибо, что за меня это высказали)) А я хотел по кусочкам в  коменте хотел довести до конца подсказки...)

Comment: @Regent, логика поворота? Ок. С 0 до 270° происходит сдвиг каждого квадрата корабля на на 9*индекс квадрата вперёд. От 90° до 180° происходит то же самое

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Если честно уже сам путаюсь.

Comment: @Flippy если корабль был `35, 45, 55, 65`, то после приведённого вами кода он станет `35, 56, 77, 98`, что вообще на корабль не похоже.

Comment: @Flippy если корабль был `35, 45, 55, 65` и это 0 градусов, то 270 градусов - это, получается, `62, 63, 64, 65`, если вращать "голову", а "хвост" держать фиксированным, то есть на `65`.

Comment: Перепутал, наоборот у меня позиции - `65 55 45 35`

Comment: У вас в этих ветках ifов что-то напутано со сравнениями tt. Вместо логики разворотов лучше использовать логику состояний. из 0 и 2 переходим в 1, из 1 и 3 в 2, и тд

Comment: Окончательно запутался. Выходит поворот с 0 на 270 и с 90 на 180 не будут одинаково работать?

Comment: Именно так. Фиксирую хвост

Comment: @vp_arth, не понял. Я три часа голову ломал, еле все это придумал.

Comment: Всмысле из 1 и 3 переходим в 2?!

Comment: @Flippy подождите. Вот у вас `65, 55, 45, 35`. После преобразования получается `65, 66, 67, 68`, то есть фиксированной остаётся голова, под которой я подразумеваю первый элемент списка.

Comment: в состояние 2(180) переходим из 1(90) по часовой, или из 3(270) против часовой. Отрисовываем состояние 2 => `(x*10, y), (x*10, y+1), (x*10, y+2)...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Храним только базовые координаты, длину и текущее состояние разворота.
Всё остальное вычисляемо из этих данных.

Демка на коленке:

```
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Ship ship = new Ship(4, 1, 3, 5); // 35, 
    ship.print();
    System.out.println("Clockwise");
    ship.turn(true).print();
    ship.turn(true).print();
    ship.turn(true).print();
    ship.turn(true).print();

    System.out.println("Counter-clockwise");
    ship.turn(false).print();
    ship.turn(false).print();
    ship.turn(false).print();
    ship.turn(false).print();


  }
}

public class Ship
{
  private int state;
  private int x;
  private int y;
  private int length;
  public Ship(int length, int initialState, int x, int y)
  {
    state = initialState;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.length = length;
  }

  public Ship turn(boolean clockwise) {
    if (clockwise) {
      state = (state + 1) % 4;
    } else {
      state = (state + 3) % 4;
    }
    return this;
  }
  public Ship print() {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      switch (state) {
        case 0: System.out.print("("+(10*x+y-i)+")"); break;   // N
        case 1: System.out.print("("+(10*(x+i)+y)+")"); break; // E
        case 2: System.out.print("("+(10*x+y+i)+")"); break;   // S
        case 3: System.out.print("("+(10*(x-i)+y)+")"); break; // W
      }
    }
    System.out.println("");
    return this;
  }
}
```

Comment: Мде.... что самое ужасное: самый первый неадекватный  ответ другого участника висит с 5-тью плюсами...

Answer (score 5):

Мы выполняем ту или иную операцию в случае если `tt == n` и `ckw == false` или `tt == n + 1` и `ckw == true`. Следовательно, если для случая `ckw == false` мы увеличим сравниваемое значение на 1, то потом нам нужно будет проверить только случай `tt == n + 1`. Такую цепочку проверок легко организовать при помощи оператора `switch`

**Update** как поправил меня @vp_arth вместо switch (val) лучше использовать `switch (val % 4)`. Тогда можно убрать проверку `case 4:`

```java
public void turn(boolean ckw) {
  int val = tt;
  if (!ckw)
    val++;
  switch (val % 4) {
    case 1:
      //b -> c
      break;
    case 2:
      //c -> d
      break;
    case 3:
      //d -> a
      break;
    case 0:
      //a -> b
      break;
  }
  if (ckw)
    tt++
  else
    tt--;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53875/discussion-on-answer-by-anton-shchyrov------).

Answer (score 2):

Если не отходить от того, что координаты корабля хранятся в `ArrayList`, то можно сделать так. В методе `turn` вычисляется новое значение `tt`, после чего координаты корабля считаются заново с учетом нового значения `tt` и фиксированной точки корабля (например, головы).

```
public void turn(boolean ckw)
{
    tt += ckw ? 1 : -1;
    tt = (tt + 4) % 4;
    int sign = (tt == 1 || tt == 2) ? 1 : -1;
    int shift = (tt % 2 == 0) ? 10 : 1;
    int head = col.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < col.size(); i++)
    {
        int newNum = head + sign * shift * i;
        col.set(i, newNum);
    }
}
```

Предполагается, что корабли могут быть только в виде одной линии. Также не учитывается то, что после поворота корабль может "выйти" за край поля.